# How do I access the Ember Data Store from a service?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember CLI application. I'm trying to access the Ember Data Store from a service (service name: users.js) like this:

```
console.log(this.store.peekAll('accounts').toArray());
```

I am calling this service from a route and when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error while processing route: accounts Cannot read property 'peekAll' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'peekAll' of undefined
```

I was able to access the Data Store from the route but not from the service. After some searching, I believe that this is how it works. How do I access the store from a service?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured this out:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service('store'),

    getAccounts: function() {
        console.log(this.get('store').peekAll('accounts').toArray());
    }    
});
```

Comment: if the name of the service is the same as the instance you dont need to specify it.  So it can be simplified to `store: Ember.inject.service(),`